Azure DevOps YAML pipeline task output variable is truncating opening bracket from JSON string
I have the following YAML pipeline task:
- task: PowerShell@2
  name: ReadrbacFromTemplate
  displayName: Read RBAC Assignments from Template
  inputs:
    filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Get-AzRolesFromTemplate.ps1'
    arguments: '-BuildDirectory "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
    showWarnings: true

The file containing the script is working fine in a local PowerShell session on my machine.
The last few lines of the script are:
$roleAssignmentsJson = ConvertTo-Json $roleAssignments
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RoleAssignmentsObject]$roleAssignmentsJson"

Even when I test converting the JSON string back to an object, it works:
$assignments = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $roleAssignmentsJson

However, in the YAML pipeline, the JSON string prints missing the opening bracket.
So, the next task in the pipeline fails with this error:
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid array passed in, ']' expected. (1): [

And I confirmed that the first task, does output the string missing the opening bracket as such:
    {
        "PrincipalId":  "PLACEHOLDER",
        "RoleDefinitionId":  "b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
    },
    {
        "PrincipalId":  "PLACEHOLDER",
        "RoleDefinitionId":  "00482a5a-887f-4fb3-b363-3b7fe8e74483"
    },
    {
        "PrincipalId":  "PLACEHOLDER",
        "RoleDefinitionId":  "73c42c96-874c-492b-b04d-ab87d138a893"
    }
]

I spent good hours on this and not sure what am I missing.
Thanks.

The pipeline variable can only receive one-line string type value. If you pass a multi-line value to a pipeline variable, it only receives the first line.
For your case, you can use the parameter '-Compress' on the 'ConvertTo-Json' cmdlet to convert the object to be a one-line JSON-formatted string. Then pass the one-line string as the value of the pipeline variable.
$roleAssignmentsJson = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $roleAssignments -Compress
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RoleAssignmentsObject]$roleAssignmentsJson"

